# iPod nano 6th gen Syncing fails no matter which program I use

Tags: sync, ipod, nano

Before my question is marked as a duplicate I have heard that is a binary blob workaround is possible. How do I do this? Because without it I get unsupported checksum type no matter what music player I use. I have tried Amarok,Clementine, gtkpod, banshee, and Rhythmbox. Please help. Oh also  for the workaround step by step instructions please as I don't know how to code. And I know of the windows virtual machine/iTunes solution and I have been using that but want to try to get something more native if possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know know that it is impossible to sync this gen iPod so therefore ignore my question (also I lost my iPod so it no longer matters).

Comment: You can delete the question then.